# How do I reference multiple cells in one sheet in one cell in another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and I have two sheets in one document (SHEET1 and SHEET2). I want to be able to use a formula that allows me to:

- If cell A1, B1, D1 and F1 in SHEET1 have an `s` in them
- Then cell A1 in SHEET2 automatically inputs an `s` in it

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In `SHEET2` in cell `A1`, add the following formula:

`=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1="s";Sheet1!B1="s";Sheet1!D1="s";Sheet1!F1="s");"s";"invalid")`

Is says:

> If A1, B1, D1 and F1 in sheet 1 *all* contain an *s* then write **s** else write **invalid**

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that the cells `A1`, `B1`, etc. are in a different sheet (ie. `SHEET1`). In which case you need to prefix the cell references with `SHEET1!`.

Comment: @w3d I think you just added the 100th upvote on the google-spreadsheets tag

Answer (score 0):

*Slightly* shorter:

```
=if(countif({Sheet1!A1:B1,Sheet1!D1,Sheet1!F1},"s")=4,"s","invalid")
```

[IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)